# Unable to send file in out directory WSO2 ESB

Tags: proxy, wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I have a simple vfs based proxy service. I want to poll file "DiscardedContracts.csv" and I want to add  time with file name and move it to Out directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ContractsDiscardedFileReader"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="vfs">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property expression="fn:concat('DiscardedContracts', get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss'), '.csv')"
                   name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"/>
         <log separator="==-------Going to move discarded contract file in out directory---------=="/>
         <log level="custom" separator="==-------File--------==">
            <property expression="fn:concat('DiscardedContracts', get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss'), '.csv')"
                      name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"/>
         </log>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint name="FileEpr">
               <address uri="vfs:file:///opt/file/contracts/Out/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <sequence key="DeliveriesFileProcessingFaultSequence"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.CreateFolder">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:file:///opt/file/contracts/Fail</parameter>
   <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.LockReleaseSameNode">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.Build">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:file:///opt/file/contracts/Out/</parameter>
   <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">30</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///opt/file/mysql</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.AutoLockRelease">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAttribute">lastmodifiedtimestamp</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAscending">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.DistributedLock">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

But Problem is I am able to concat datetime with file name but file is not moving to Out directory properly. It create a **response.xml** Which contains my data. I don't know how file name and extension is changing. Need help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because you have not set `transport.vfs.ReplyFileName`. (You have only logged it.) Its default value is `response.xml`.

If you take `transport.vfs.ReplyFileName` property out of the log mediator, it should work.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/VFS+Transport

**Update**: Set `scope="transport"` to the property like below.

```
<property expression="fn:concat('DiscardedContracts', get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss'), '.csv')" 
    scope="transport"
    name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"/>
```

Comment: But I have set it. You can check that is the first thing in my sequence. I have a property and I am concatenating system date in it. After that I have logged it.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. Try setting `scope="transport"` in the property. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks dude. Banging my head with walls.